# How Can i get length of proxy in JS?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get length of array in proxy in JS how can I do?

as you can see I have length 25 and I want to take that number because that's the length of my array how can I do it?

I've already tried by doing JSON.stringify but that's returning me undefined

[THAT'S THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe0fL.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. Instead, copy and paste them directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Proxy Object)).length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this short version

```
Object.values(Proxy Object).length
```